# How to Swap the key of dictionary with its value

Tags: python

I have dictionary

> d= {1:[2],2:[3],3:[4]}

i want to swap only a particular key with its values.

so if I want to swap the first key then the dictionary will be

```
d= {2:[1,3],3:[4]}
```

how I can achieve this?

I tried

> d.iteritems()

but it swaps all the keys of the dictionary.

Thanks in advance. and this is not homework.

Comment: What if the value you are swapping is a list with more than one element - or an empty list?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it . It is fixed that the value we are swapping is a list with only one element. and it cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach `dict.pop` and `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
d= {1:[2],2:[3],3:[4]}
key_to_swap = 1

for value in d.pop(key_to_swap):
    d.setdefault(value, []).append(key_to_swap)
print(d)
```